# Copying and pasting Multiple cells in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

New to Excel VBA and looking for some guidance, please.

I have the following situation in Excel.  TodayDate is today's date.  Sheet has 365 columns, one for each day of the year.  Everyday I want to run a macro that will pick out ONLY the non-zero values, then copy them, then paste them into another sheet in the same workbook.

Worksheet A

```
TodayDate
0
45
0
12
6
0
29
```

So the result for this particular day would be:

Worksheet B

```
TodayDate
45
12
6
29
```

Note: the number of non-zero entries is variable.  Can be zero on a particular date or it can be a dozen or more.  Also, which column of interest will fall on also varies, due mostly to leap-years and the fact that I need to run it for any particular day of the year.

I've been looking around and trying different things but have not found anything that works exactly as needed.

Comment: Take a look at the Advanced Filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses **Sheet1** and **Sheet2:**

```
Sub GrabData()
    Dim d As Date, i As Long, N As Long
    d = Date
    Dim j As Long, K As Long, s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 1 To 365
        If s1.Cells(1, i) = d Then Exit For
    Next i
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1
    For j = 1 To N
        If s1.Cells(j, i).Value <> 0 Then
            s2.Cells(K, 1).Value = s1.Cells(j, i).Value
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Worked perfectly.